# TensorFlow model.save() insufficient permissions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to save my TF models to a gcs bucket with `model.save("bucket_path")` but keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-file.py", line 765, in <module>
    model.save(bucket_save_path)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1979, in save
    signatures, options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 134, in save_model
    signatures, options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py", line 80, in save
    save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 981, in save
    utils_impl.get_or_create_variables_dir(export_dir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/utils_impl.py", line 214, in get_or_create_variables_dir
    file_io.recursive_create_dir(variables_dir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 465, in recursive_create_dir
    recursive_create_dir_v2(dirname)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 480, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}
when initiating an upload to gs://bucket_name/mode_name/
```

I made sure to login with `gsutil auth login` and `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<JSON_FILE_PATH>`. So I am not sure why I keep getting this permission error.

Note: This is being run in a GCP VM and is being saved in a GCS Bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has probably to do with the permissions on the bucket for the account you are using to run the code under. The service account the VM is running under (most likely the default compute service account) should have write permissions to the bucket you are using. If you are using fine-grained ACLs on your bucket this command will grant write permissions:

```
gsutil acl ch -u $PROJECT_NUMBER@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com:WRITE gs://example-bucket
```

If you want to be able to the TF code under your own account use the following command, of course, your own account needs write-permissions on the bucket as well.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

It basically boils down to the following questions:

1. Under which account do you run the code on the VM?

   - Service account (set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
   - User account (use application default login)
2. What kind of bucket permissions do you use?

   - Fine-grained access (`gsutil iam ch`)
   - Uniform bucket-level access (`gsutil acl ch`)